# `no implicit conversion of String into Integer` error when trying to get value from hash

Tags: ruby, hash

I am trying to get Value in a hash using its Key just like below.

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

$, = ", "
months = Hash.new( "month" )
months = {"1" => "January", "2" => "February"}

keys = months.keys["1"]
puts "#{keys}"
```

I get following error

```
main.rb:7:in `[]': no implicit conversion of String into Integer (TypeError)
    from main.rb:7:in `<main>'
```

Why am I getting above error?

Comment: `months.keys` is an `Array` of keys, and arrays must be subscripted by integers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is just

```
months["1"]
```

Why are you using `keys` method? That returns all the keys as an array. And therefore you can access that just with numbers. That's what the error is saying.